# Access-Control-Allow-Credentials missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, cors

I am trying to run ajax call from a site, to a MVC 5 application hosted in  Azure.
 However that call must specific 'withCredentials' parameter.

```
 xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
 }
```

After specific that argument browser return error '(expecting „true” in CORS header „Access-Control-Allow-Credentials”'

To overcome that i have added custom headers in Web.config. But Azure somehow remove them expect, Test2 header which is present in response.

My webconfig

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Test2" value="justTest" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer></configuration>
```

I have also tried to specific header arg. from c# code.

```
 HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
 HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Test", "true");
```

Same result. Cors headers are removed.

How to add cors header to response?

Comment: have you enabled CORS in your azure deployed webapi? like config.EnableCors();

Comment: i am not using webapi. I am making call to MVC 5 application.

Comment: its already answered here. have a look - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663667/enable-cors-in-azure-web

Comment: Thanks but this is another case. Correct Access-Control-Allow-Origin is typed in azure portal (webapp -> api -> cors )  so ajax calls to actions which don't require withCredentials works as intended.